# Array works when manually written, but not when loaded from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a password recommend script. I wish to warn users when they use a commonly used password. I wish to load the passwords from an external text file. How-ever for some reason it seems it only checks the last entry in the array.

When using this code to load the array:

```
var commonPass = new Array;
jQuery.get('/static/commonPass.txt', function(data){
    commonPass = data.trim().split('\n');
    console.debug(commonPass);
});
```

This is the result i get from console.debug:

```
["password", "12345678"]
```

and when I then enter "password" into the field it does not recognize the password as part of the array.

How-ever if i state commonPass manually as an array:

```
var commonPass = ["password", "12345678"];
```

it works without any problems.

This is my full code so far:
http://pastebin.com/LeTtEL83

If you wish any further info, please comment and I will do my best to answer.

Comment: So it's failing on `if(jQuery.inArray(pswd, commonPass) > -1) {` when you use the split method?  Have you tried outputting commonPass before that check?

Comment: What is the contents of the `commonPass.txt` file?

Comment: Current content of commonpass: http://pastebin.com/Z4Sxzmpa
 - and Yes, the result of logging the commonpass is the same as previous debug `["password
", "12345678"]`

Comment: The usual way to do this is to send the password to the server, check if it's in the list, and return a boolean, not get the entire list with ajax each time.

Comment: The entire list is not loaded each time, i made sure of that. It is loaded once and put into an array which is then checked each time. I believe posting to a server would take much time and inconvenience.

Comment: What you've done is relying on an async function to have completed by the time someone hits a key, and there's no guarantee of that

Comment: could code something that locks the password field till its has loaded, ways around that. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So what exactly does the two console logs give you ?

Comment: And it should be noted that if you only need to load the array on pageload you don't really need ajax, you could just echo it directly into a variable from the serverside.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow what you mean? - And the first console log gives me `["password
", "12345678"]`  and the second one `["password
", "12345678"]`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by altering the split argument from `.split('\n');` to `.split(/\r?\n/);` - Seems to have been an issue with whitespace.